# 3 Warnings AppIcon

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, icons

I used to use older Xcode and I added the logos and everything was fine, now I'm using the latest version of 'Xcode 7.3 beta 3' and I got 3 warnings as you can see in the picture.

Does anybody know how to remove them or fix this problem?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution is , just select the unassigned image and delete it via delete button. Clean and Build. Done.

[image]

Edit:-

[image]

Comment: I did, but I don't know about the clean, how can I do it?

Comment: I'm doing it, hold on, my laptop is slow only with Xcode :)

Comment: it's ok. No problem . i will wait.

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help.

Comment: I went to "App Icons and Launch Image >> Launch Image Source" and I changed it to "Use Asset Catalog" and I got the following error http://oi64.tinypic.com/210g9ia.jpg the thing is, how can I make the application run on all iPhones? You know, like WhatsApp

Comment: yes. for that you need to add lunch images. sorry. i was bzy . wait i will give you pic.

Comment: Welcome @Seema Happy to help .